# Associating list value in python dictionary with relevant key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a 2-column tab-separated input that I would like to populate a dictionary in `python`. The first column associates to the key (there are duplicates) and the second column associates to the value.

Sample input:

```
cat tail
cat whisker
cat meow
cat black
dog tail
dog paw
dog bark
bird    beak
```

I have written the following code, which produces an (albeit wrong) output that contains the dictionary format that I am looking for, which associates **one** key from col1 to all of its values in col2.

The code that I have been using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

keys = []
values = []

with open('animal-trial', "rU") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        keys.append(line[0])
        values.append(line[1])
    d = {}
    for k,v in zip(keys, values):
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    print d
```

I have looked up other references [[HERE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730836/merge-two-lists-one-as-keys-one-as-values-into-a-dict-in-python), [[HERE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271385/how-do-i-combine-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python) and [[HERE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115034/python-dictionary-with-repetition-of-key-and-value), however, all of the suggestions, including with `defaultdicts` bring me to the same output, rather than the desired output.

The **actual** output is:

```
{'cat': ['tail']}
{'cat': ['tail', 'whisker']}
{'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow']}
{'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
{'dog': ['tail'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
{'dog': ['tail', 'paw'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
{'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
{'bird': ['beak'], 'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
```

The **desired** output is

```
{'bird': ['beak'], 'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
```

Can anyone point me to where I am making an error or have a more comprehensive solution so that the final result is `one` dictionary?

Comment: You *do* have one dictionary. Your indentation must be different to what you have posted; your final print statement is probably inside the for loop.

Comment: @owwoow14 Thats right your code works I guess. Indent back the statement `print d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the key is present, if it's present then append and if it's not then create a list with single element:

```
d = {}
with open('a12', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            a = line.split()
            if a[0] not in d:
                d[a[0]] = [a[1]]
            else:
                d[a[0]].append(a[1])
print d
```

Output:

```
{'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black'], 'bird': ['beak'], 'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark']}
```

---

## With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name', header=None, sep='\s+')
print df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark'], 'bird': ['beak'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
```

Comment: why not using a regular dict?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki OK?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an input file called `f_input.txt`.

You can also use `groupby`from `itertools` module like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = list(k.rstrip().split() for k in open("f_input.txt", 'r'))
final = {}
for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x : x[0]):
    final[k] = list(k[1] for k in list(v))

print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'bird': ['beak'], 'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose you have split your input on "\n"

```
 d = {}
 tab = ['cat tail', 'cat whisker', 'cat meow', 'cat black', 'dog tail', 'dog paw', 'dog bark', 'bird beak']
 for i  in tab:
    try:
        d[i.split(" ")[0]] += [i.split(" ")[1]]
    except KeyError:
        d[i.split(" ")[0]] = [i.split(" ")[1]]
```

output

> {'bird': ['beak'], 'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark'], 'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black']}

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with default defaultdict

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    keys = []
    values = []

    with open('animal-trial', "rU") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.split()
            keys.append(line[0])
            values.append(line[1])
        d = defaultdict(list)
        for k,v in zip(keys, values):
            d[k].append(v)
        print(dict(d))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Output:

```
{'cat': ['tail', 'whisker', 'meow', 'black'], 'bird': ['beak'], 'dog': ['tail', 'paw', 'bark']}
```